# What exactly does Dropbox do when it syncs?

Tags: backup, sync, dropbox

When I upload or create folders on a system I have configured with Dropbox, what exactly happens on my other systems equipped with that same Dropbox account?

By that, I mean:  does Dropbox download a complete version of the new file and store it on the remote system (eager consistency)?  Or does it update the metadata for that file, indicating a new version is available, should a user choose to access it (lazy consistency)?

My issue is that I would like to use Dropbox as a convenient way to distribute small files I need to work on often, while also using it as a backup to a large amount of critical files I don't want to lose.

Not all of my Dropbox-equipped systems have 1 TB of space available.  In fact, I use both my phone and tablet to look at files periodically, and they definitely don't have 1 TB of space available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies.

**The PC versions** (Windows, OS X, Linux) run as a regular application with user privileges, and store files on the regular filesystem. There is no method that would allow Dropbox to download files on demand when another app tries to access them, therefore downloading complete files is the only method that *can* work.

So, by default, all 1 TB would be downloaded. However, the app allows certain folders to be excluded (called "selective sync" in the UI) so you don't need to download all files to every single PC.

(Some other tools such as Wuala instead choose to expose their *internal* storage through some sort of emulated network-share access, where the sync app eventually receives all open & read requests, and can implement on-demand download. However, this usually needs at least Administrator privileges, something that Dropbox has strongly avoided requiring so far.)

**The Android app** mostly acts as just a thin file browser – it caches basic metadata (file names) locally, but downloads files on demand as you try to open them through the app. Recent files remain cached for a short while (around 250 MB), and you can "star" files to sync & cache them permanently, but they always have to be opened through the Dropbox app.

(The files are cached in the app's private storage directory – technically they *can* be accessed directly through the filesystem, but it is somewhat tricky to navigate to.)